# React: How to wrap input text?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, word-wrap, html-input

I have a React table written with material-ui like this:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    overflowX: "auto"
  },
  table: {
    minWidth: 700
  }
});

let id = 0;
function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  id += 1;
  return { id, name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData("Frozen yoghurt", 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData("Ice cream sandwich", 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData("Eclair", 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData("Cupcake", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9)
];

function SimpleTable(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <Table className={classes.table}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Fat (g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Carbs (g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Protein (g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.id}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.name}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">
                <input defaultValue={row.calories}/>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Paper>
  );
}

SimpleTable.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleTable);
```

Some of my table's cells have `<input />`s (here just `calories` because it's an example). How can I get the text in the input to wrap if it's to longer than the input? Currently, it pushes the other text away and hides it.

Comment: could you please revise your question? I dont understand this `How can I get the text in the input to wrap if it's to longer than the input?`

Comment: Maybe you need a `<textarea/>` instead of an `<input/>`

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii What I mean is, if you start writing more chacacters into the input then at one point the sequence of words would be longer than the input box (similar to how it is here with the comments on stackoverflow).

Comment: so try to make fixed width for the input?

Answer (score 0):

You can use css property `overflowWrap: "break-word"`. Read more about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but apparently it has no effect on '<input />`.

Comment: Ouch, I missed that. I think the best you can use is textarea. It will do exactly what you want. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea